# How to create function for jquery .keydown?

Tags: jquery

$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var test_func=function(ev)
        {
            alert(ev.keyCode);
        };
         ....
        $(document).keydown(test_func(ev));
    });

I wanna do the next, if I press somebutton on keyboard, I'll see alert with a code of key which I pressed. But I see only 'ev is not defined' in my firebug =|

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should look like this (no parameters in the call):

```
$(document).keydown(test_func);
```

The event will be passed as the first argument, and you can use [`ev.which`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L468) since jquery normalizes this across browsers :)

When you call a function like this you want to pass the function itself as what to call when the event happens, so use `method`.  If you use `method(something)` it's trying to invoke the method *right then* (with a variable `ev`, that it can't find) and assign the *result* of that method as the event handler, rather than the method itself.

You could also use an anonymous method, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    alert(e.which);
  });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks! =)
I use usual anonymous method, but now... Now I have a special task =) I've got two html objects which use the same method, that's way I created a one for two objects.